# GitHub images appear in ReadMe.md, not in published page

Tags: image, github, html, github-flavored-markdown

On GitHub, I created a ReadMe.md with screenshots

but when I publish the website, it doesn't show the image. I used

`![alt tag](https://raw.github.com/username/projectname/branch/path/to/img.png)`

and

`<img src="https://raw.github.com/username/projectname/branch/path/to/img.png" alt="https://raw.github.com/username/projectname/branch/path/to/img.png">`

But nothing works. What format can I insert images where it will display on both ReadMe.md and the Webpage?

Link ReadMe.md: https://github.com/Sonihal/moveclient/blob/master/README.md

Link to Webpage: http://sonihal.github.io/moveclient

Comment: You are using `https://github.com/Sonihal/moveclient/blob/master/group_name_and_id.JPG` in the webpage. Try changing it to `https://github.com/Sonihal/moveclient/raw/master/group_name_and_id.JPG` (change *blob* to *raw*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your website is trying to load images from the wrong link:

```
<img src="https://github.com/Sonihal/moveclient/blob/master/group_name_and_id.JPG" alt="https://github.com/Sonihal/moveclient/blob/master/group_name_and_id.JPG">
```

You should update it to use the **raw** image link in github:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[USER]/[REPO]/[BRANCH]/[PATH_TO_IMAGE]`

Example: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sonihal/moveclient/master/group_name_and_id.JPG`

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sonihal/moveclient/master/group_name_and_id.JPG]

In `Readme.md` file, you can use both because it seems Github markdown understands it and wrap it automatically to get the image.